# Rで系統樹を作成したい

Tags: r

Rを使ってnj法による無根系統樹を作成したいですが、いまいち上手くいきません。
手元には以下のようなCSVファイルをもとに作成します。値は各地点間のFstです。

詳しい作成方法を教えてくれる方いたらよろしくお願い致します。

[image]

Comment: 例えばこういうページもありますが, これを見てもできませんか? https://www1.doshisha.ac.jp/~mjin/R/Chap_42/42.html

Comment: @user12399423 コメントありがとうございます。
出来ました。